# Finding the longest string from a list of ten strings in C?

Tags: c, string

I will have to take the input from user and find the longest input from those 10 strings..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
char str[10][10]
printf("Enter strings:")
scanf("%s", str)

}
```

If I take the user input like this, would it store the strings in str two dimensional array? To find out the longest string first I would find the length of each strings and use max_length function to determine the longest string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to store all of the strings, just the longest one entered so far.
Note that you do need to define a maximum length of string to avoid buffer overrun.

For example:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 1024

char last_entered_string[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
char longest_entered_string[MAX_STRING_SIZE] = ""; /* Must be initialized. */

scanf("%1023s", last_entered_string); /* Read one less to allow for
                                         null terminator. */
```

Use a loop to accept the ten inputs and compare with the longest string. If the last entered string is longer then copy it into the longest string. As this is homework I'll not provide any further code.

Comment: Is there a easier way to do this? I am messed up!

Comment: @user1687755, I can't think of a simpler way. Take it one step at time: 1) Write a program that accepts one input and prints it. 2) Extend the program to accept 10 inputs (`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` and prints each one. 3) Modify it meet your final requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. You have to loop through and read all strings.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
scanf("%s", str[i]);
```

Also, you are missing some semi-colons!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the longest string put and save it for all the string received.

```
int main()
{
 char *str = NULL;
 char *compare;
 printf("Enter strings:");
 scanf("%s", compare);
 if (strlen(str) < strlen(compare))
    str = strdup(compare);
 return(0);
}
```

And if you want to store all of users input (considering you can have just 10 string from the user)you can do this :

```
int main()
{
 char **array;
 char *str;
 int x = 0;
 int shortest;
 array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
 while (x < 10)
  {
   scanf("%s", str)
   array[x] = strdup(str);
   x++;
  }
 x = 0;
 shortest = x;
 while (x < 10)
  {
   if (strlen(array[x]) > strlen(shortest))
     shortest = x;
   x++;
  }
 return (0);
}
```

shortest will be the index of the longest string in your array.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to do the best easy way possible..Will the above code work? Is it the complete program?

Comment: i did'n t test it cause i don't have gcc or something for do it but i think it works (you will have to make a function for returning the array[x] string at the end wich is the longest string). just test it it's easy to debug anyway

Answer (score 0):

Store all input in an array, then do `qsort()` it on the array entries length and then take the first (or the last, depending on how you sorted) entry.

Ok, ok ... - this might be over-engineered ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is take a nested loop and search for a `'\0'` character in the row and run a counter simultaneously. as soon as you find a `'\0'` stop the counter and store the value of counter in a separate array . so now you will have a array of 10 integers.
Now search for smallest integer in the array and... Bingo!
The corresponding row will have the shortest string.
I know this approach is very raw but I think it will be helpful for people with only basic knowledge of  C.

Answer (score 0):

The program presented will take 10 input strings from the user and then finally print out the longest string and its length. It will not store any other input strings than the biggest one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char str_final[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char str_temp[MAX_STR_LEN];
    unsigned int i, j, len_str;
    unsigned int num_string = 10;
    unsigned int len_max = 0;

    for (i=0; i<num_string; i++){
        printf("Enter string number: %d\n", i);
        gets(str_temp);

        for (j=0; str_temp[j]; j++);
        len_str = j;

        if(len_str > len_max){
            len_max = len_str;
            memset(str_final, 0, MAX_STR_LEN);
            memcpy(str_final, str_temp, len_str);
        }else{
            memset(str_temp, 0, MAX_STR_LEN);
        }

    }

    printf("The biggest string is: %s\n", str_final);
    printf("It's size is: %d\n", len_max);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```